# AWS ALB - new certificate required if underlying ALB is recreated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I am using a DigiCert Certificate for an AWS ALB that has a domain: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
For some reason - the underlying AWS ALB was deleted and a new one was created which also maps to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

There has been no other change to the underlying servers.

I am now seeing a Certificate is invalid error saying its not secure.
Do I need to procure a new certificate or is it some other issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Has the certificate expired perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know DigiCert, so I guess that your certificate create trust for the IP of the ALB.

ALB are not static at all by design. This is basically a super huge cluster of HAProxy and ressources are allocated dynamically based on customers consumption. There is no way to have a static IP, that's why they give you a CNAME only.

You should seek for DNS validation or use AWS Certificate.

Comment: Thanks.. I will look into this.